# Used Twitter bootstrap in Grails, looks different

Tags: jquery, css, grails, twitter-bootstrap, color-picker

I followed a tutorial from [icodeya](http://www.icodeya.com/2012/10/grails-how-do-i-add-color-picker-in-my.html) for adding a color picker in a textfield. The twist is, I used [twitter bootstrap](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-colorpicker/) instead of the miniColor.js. But I can't get it to work.

Here is my code:

Config.groovy

```
grails.resources.modules = {
jQuery{
resource url:'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js', disposition: 'head'
}

colorPicker{
dependsOn 'jQuery'

resource url: '/js/jquery.twitterBootstrap.js', disposition: 'head'
resource url: '/css/jquery.twitterBootstrap.css'
}
}
```

/css/twitterBootStrap.css

```
 /*
    Colorpicker for Bootstrap
    Copyright 2012 Stefan Petre 
    Licensed under the Apache License v2.0
    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*/
 .colorpicker-saturation { width: 100px; height: 100px; background-image: url(/img/saturation.png); cursor: crosshair; float: left; } .colorpicker-saturation i { display: block; height: 5px; width: 5px; border: 1px solid #000; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; margin: -4px 0 0 -4px; } .colorpicker-saturation i b { display: block; height: 5px; width: 5px; border: 1px solid #fff; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; } .colorpicker-hue, .colorpicker-alpha { width: 15px; height: 100px; float: left; cursor: row-resize; margin-left: 4px; margin-bottom: 4px; } .colorpicker-hue i, .colorpicker-alpha i { display: block; height: 1px; background: #000; border-top: 1px solid #fff; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; margin-top: -1px; } .colorpicker-hue { background-image: url(/img/hue.png); } .colorpicker-alpha { background-image: url(/img/alpha.png); display: none; } .colorpicker { *zoom: 1; top: 0; left: 0; padding: 4px; min-width: 120px; margin-top: 1px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; } .colorpicker:before, .colorpicker:after { display: table; content: ""; } .colorpicker:after { clear: both; } .colorpicker:before { content: ''; display: inline-block; border-left: 7px solid transparent; border-right: 7px solid transparent; border-bottom: 7px solid #ccc; border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); position: absolute; top: -7px; left: 6px; } .colorpicker:after { content: ''; display: inline-block; border-left: 6px solid transparent; border-right: 6px solid transparent; border-bottom: 6px solid #ffffff; position: absolute; top: -6px; left: 7px; } .colorpicker div { position: relative; } .colorpicker.alpha { min-width: 140px; } .colorpicker.alpha .colorpicker-alpha { display: block; } .colorpicker-color { height: 10px; margin-top: 5px; clear: both; background-image: url(/img/alpha.png); background-position: 0 100%; } .colorpicker-color div { height: 10px; } .input-append.color .add-on i, .input-prepend.color .add-on i { display: block; cursor: pointer; width: 16px; height: 16px; }
```

In my gsp file I added:

```
<r:require module="colorPicker" / >
<script> 
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
jQuery('#myColorPicker').colorpicker();
});
</script>
<br/><br/>
```

I also added the js file in the js folder of grails. However, it looks like this:

[image]

I do not see the gradation from black to pink; It's just all pink. But when I click on a spot, say at the bottom right corner, I'd get a dark color as expected. The result from my code isn't showing that though.

I am using Version 21.0.1180.75 of Google Chrome. It really looks different from the one demoed in the eyecon.ro site.

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: No js errors? The images required by colorpicker are downloaded?

Comment: Just a suggestion here. You should download the jQuery plugin for grails. This way you don't have to define it in application resources and it will be the library grails chooses when doing ajax calls with grails tags.

Comment: Also, I would recommend creating a fiddle to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The paths for the images are incorrect. Assuming the colorpicker folder is intact from when you downloaded it, the css links to files should be `../img/*` instead of `/img/*`. The original css is wrong. The included .less file is correct, however.